# Implement get_or_create() with Rust and Diesel

Tags: rust

I just started learning Rust, and try to implement a function like Django's [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create).

Now my implementation looks too verbose[ I hope that rust can be neater.
Therefore, how can I implement this function in less verbose way?
There is probably a way to shorten nested **match** constructions below?

```rs
use log::warn;

use diesel::prelude::*;
use diesel::result;

use crate::db::{get_connection, PgPool};
use crate::models::{NewUser, User};

pub fn get_or_create_user(pool: &PgPool, email: &str) -> User {
    use crate::schema::users;

    let new_user = NewUser { email };
    let mut conn = get_connection(pool);

    let result = diesel::insert_into(users::table)
        .values(&new_user)
        .get_result(&mut conn);

    match result {
        Ok(user) => return user,
        Err(err) => match err {
            result::Error::DatabaseError(err_kind, info) => match err_kind {
                result::DatabaseErrorKind::UniqueViolation => {
                    warn!(
                        "{:?} is already exists. Info: {:?}. Skipping.",
                        new_user, info
                    );
                    // another query to DB to get existing user by email
                    let user = user_by_email(pool, new_user.email);
                    return user;
                }
                _ => {
                    panic!("Database error: {:?}", info);
                }
            },
            _ => {
                // TODO: decide how to deal with unexpected errors
                return User {
                    id: 0,
                    email: "".into(),
                };
            }
        },
    }
}

pub fn user_by_email(pool: &PgPool, user_email: &str) -> User {
    use crate::schema::users::dsl::*;

    let mut conn = get_connection(pool);

    let user = crate::schema::users::dsl::users
        .filter(email.eq(user_email))
        .first(&mut conn)
        .unwrap();
    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to the Rust community!

### get or create

You may indeed make code readable by replacing multiple nested matches with a single match that has nested patterns.

For example, we match on `Err(DatabaseError(UniqueViolation, info))` and that grabs all errors that contain a `DatabaseError` variant of Diesel `Error` enum, with inner `UniqueViolation` variant of `DatabaseErrorKind`. We bind the second value within `DatabaseError` to `info`, so we can print the info super easy too. If, for example, the `Error` is something else than `UniqueViolation`, we fall through to the next match arm.

The pattern sublanguage is like a language within a language -- you have to learn it and build your intuition about it.

The result of our effort is super readable:

```rust
match result {
    Ok(user) => return user,
    Err(DatabaseError(UniqueViolation, info)) => {
        warn!(
            "{:?} is already exists. Info: {:?}. Skipping.",
            new_user, info
        );
        // another query to DB to get existing user by email
        user_by_email(new_user.email)
    }
    Err(DatabaseError(_, info)) => {
        panic!("Database error: {:?}", info);
    }
    _ => {
        // TODO: decide how to deal with unexpected errors
        User {
            id: 0,
            email: "".into(),
        }
    }
}
```

I had an idea that you may only build one query, which would use `ON CONFLICT`, and kill two birds with one stone. Unfortunately, Diesel dsl does not seem to support `ON CONFLICT (...) DO NOTHING RETURNING *`.

### Other concerns

Syntax nitpick:

```rust
let user = schema::users::dsl::users
    .filter(email.eq(user_email))
    .first(&mut conn)
    .unwrap();
return user;
```

You may just return the user value directly, replacing the above code with this:

```rust
schema::users::dsl::users
    .filter(email.eq(user_email))
    .first(&mut conn)
    .unwrap()
```

### Result

The result is available on my github: https://github.com/pczarn/codereview/tree/81d3fcddd3921bf1b4df4bb347be5dcad3de743f/2022/9/get_or_create

I cleaned up your code, migrated to sqlite for local testing and this is what I got:

```rust
extern crate diesel;

mod schema;

use diesel::sqlite::SqliteConnection;
use diesel::prelude::*;
use dotenvy::dotenv;
use std::env;

use log::warn;

use diesel::prelude::*;

use schema::users;

#[derive(Debug, Insertable)]
#[diesel(table_name = users)]
struct NewUser<'a> {
    email: &'a str,
}

#[derive(Queryable)]
pub struct User {
    id: i32,
    email: String,
}

pub fn get_or_create_user(email: &str) -> User {
    use diesel::result::{Error::DatabaseError, DatabaseErrorKind::UniqueViolation};

    let new_user = NewUser { email };
    let mut conn = get_connection();

    let result = diesel::insert_into(users::table)
        .values(&new_user)
        .get_result(&mut conn);

    match result {
        Ok(user) => return user,
        Err(DatabaseError(UniqueViolation, info)) => {
            warn!(
                "{:?} is already exists. Info: {:?}. Skipping.",
                new_user, info
            );
            // another query to DB to get existing user by email
            user_by_email(new_user.email)
        }
        Err(DatabaseError(_, info)) => {
            panic!("Database error: {:?}", info);
        }
        _ => {
            // TODO: decide how to deal with unexpected errors
            User {
                id: 0,
                email: "".into(),
            }
        }
    }
}

pub fn user_by_email(user_email: &str) -> User {
    use schema::users::dsl::*;

    let mut conn = get_connection();

    let user = schema::users::dsl::users
        .filter(email.eq(user_email))
        .first(&mut conn)
        .unwrap();
    return user;
}

pub fn get_connection() -> SqliteConnection {
    dotenv().ok();

    let database_url = env::var("DATABASE_URL").expect("DATABASE_URL must be set");
    SqliteConnection::establish(&database_url)
        .unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("Error connecting to {}", database_url))
}

fn main() {
    get_or_create_user("example@example.com");
    get_or_create_user("example@example.com");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for so detailed explanation! 

I definitely need time to realize how to apply matches with all nested matches, unwrap*(), ?, ok() and so on ) 
Your answer helped me a lot.